# Limit records in sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite

When I enlarge my db, I noticed that I can commit only 500 records, but I need more. Why it is limited? And how I can unlock it for more?

Comment: upd-don`t blame me for newbie, I just want to understand what I`m doing wrong.

Comment: Oh, my fail. My IDE(pycharm) shows only 500 records...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly 500 records is not the SQLite limit.

According to official documentation.

> **Maximum Number Of Rows In A Table**
>
> The theoretical maximum number of rows in a table is 2<sup>64</sup> (18446744073709551616 or about 1.8e+19). This limit is unreachable since the maximum database size of 140 terabytes will be reached first. A 140 terabytes database can hold no more than approximately 1e+13 rows, and then only if there are no indices and if each row contains very little data.

Anyway, take a read at SQLite official documentation about [Limits in SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html) for more info